Muffler broke off, can I leave It?
My muffler fell off and now my engine is running smoother, why? I have 2012 Nissan Maxima which has a y converter. And dual muffler. Catalytic converter has been coming back on check engine light for 6 months. But now that my muffler fell off my rpms are normal and not high. I used some string to put it in place, not perfect but is it okay to drive like this? If snow gets in there an I doomed?
